# Check If Valid Jquery Date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if the user has selected a valid date. When i call `getDateFilteredComments()` method.
I need to capture that in the `IF` condition.

```
 $("#StartDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "d M y"
});

function getDateFilteredComments() {

  if (Condition) {
    alert("Valid");
  } else {
    alert("Not Valid");
  }

}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't the user select a valid date, what other options are there with a datepicker ?

Comment: @adeneo user can type random text as well,so i need to restrict that

Comment: `<input type="date" required />`

Comment: @adeneo this wont help, can i restrict the user from entering a date, but he should be able to select it

Comment: Generally you wouldn't care if the user decided to focus the input and type something strange, rather than using the datepicker, you'd pick that up during serverside validation anyway. If you have to check if a date is valid, I suppose you have to check if adheres to the format you've given.

Comment: isNaN( d.getTime() )

Comment: hahahah the jquery datepicker never gives an invalid date

Comment: maybe you can add attibute readonly so that he can't type invalid date?

Comment: You only need a date that pick from a datapicker not a random input right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict the user to input anything and accept `Date` from the data picker try this one [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sv04uhgn/).

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Glad to help you friend.

Answer (score 3):

just convert your string to date using new Date(dateString) also change your date format I don't think that's valid

```
function getDateFilteredComments() {

  if (new Date($("#StartDate").val()) != "Invalid Date") {
    alert("Valid");
  } else {
    alert("Not Valid");
  }

}
```

Comment: Couldn't use the ````.val()```` but I was able to use ````.toString()```` and the same logic is applied (i.e. Invalid Date is still returned if fails to convert).  Not sure if it changed, or if my constructor was different.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function fu(){

 var text = document.getElementById("it").value;
 var take = text.split('/');
  var mo = parseInt(take[0], 10);
 var da = parseInt(take[1], 10);
  var ye = parseInt(take[2], 10);
 var date = new Date(ye,mo-1,da);
 if (date.getFullYear() == ye && date.getMonth() + 1 == mo && date.getDate()
   ==  da) {
   alert('Valid date input');
    } else {
    alert('Invalid date input');
  }
   }
</script>


<input type="text" id="it" placeholder="Add date..."/>

<input type="submit" id="ad" onclick="fu()" value="testd"/>
```